# ListItem child doesn't fill full parent height (click counts as exit/escape)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've implemented a drawer similar to the example shown [here](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer). For working reproductions, please follow the link above and edit the Responsive Drawer on `Stackblitz` or `Codesandbox`. All that needs to be done to see the issue is to add `onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.tagName)}` to the `<ListItem button>`.

[image]

Everything works as expected, except if you click on the top/bottom edge of a `ListItem` - in that case, I'm not able to get to the value assigned to the `ListItem`, and it's treated like an escape/cancellation and closes the drawer. In the `<ListItem>` the method `onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.tagName)` will correctly log `SPAN` if you click in the middle, but will log `DIV` and be unresponsive if you click on the edge.
Example of one of the list items:

```
<Collapse in = {isOpen} timeout = 'auto' unmountOnExit>
    <List component = 'div' disablePadding>
        <ListItem button key = {'Something'} value = {'Something'} sx = {{pl: 4}} onClick = {(e) => handleSelect(e)}>
            <ListItemIcon><StarBorder /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary = {'Something'} />
        </ListItem>
    </List>
</Collapse>
```

Overall structure of the drawer:

```
<List>
    <Box>
        <ListItem />
        <Collapse>
            <ListItem />
            <ListItem />
        </Collapse>
    </Box>
</List>
```

onClick:

```
const handleSelect = (e) =>
{
    const parentTag = e.target.tagName

    if (parentTag === 'DIV')
    {
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML)

        for (let child of e.target.children)
        {
            if (child.tagName === 'SPAN')
            {
                console.log(child.innerHTML)
            }
        }
        
    }
    else if (parentTag === 'SPAN')
    {
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
    }
}
```

If you were to click in the middle of a `ListItem`, then `parentTag === 'SPAN'`, and the console will log `Something` as expected.

But if you click on the top or bottom edge, then `parentTag === 'DIV'`, and `console.log(e.target.innerHTML)` will show the following:

```
<div class="MuiListItemIcon-root..."><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root..."><path d="..."></path> 
</svg></div><div class="MuiListItemText-root..."><span class="MuiTypography-root...">
Something
</span></div><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root..."><span class="css..."><span 
class="MuiTouchRipple..."></span></span></span>
```

There are three `<span>` elements, and I need the value of the first. However, `console.log(child.innerHTML)` always logs the later ones:

```
<span class="css..."><span 
class="MuiTouchRipple..."></span></span>
```

Is there a way to get to the actual value I need? Or a better way to handle this, maybe by making the `<div>` unclickable/expanding the click area of the `ListItem`?

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/)

Comment: @onkarruikar There is a link in the first sentence with full reproductions on stackblitz and codesandbox. Use whichever you prefer, and all you need to do is add `onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.tagName)}` to the `ListItem` to see the issue.

Comment: @onkarruikar Right, the section to which I linked has buttons for editing the code on Stackblitz or Codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can traverse till topmost parent div and search the content span from there:

```js
 const handleSelect = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    // get to the parent
    while (!target.classList.contains('MuiButtonBase-root')) {
      target = target.parentElement;
    }
   
    // get the content span
    target = target.querySelector('.MuiTypography-root');
    
    // utilize the content
    setContent(`Clicked on: ${selected.tagName}, content: ${target.innerHTML}`);
    console.log(selected);
    handleDrawerToggle();
  };
```

Even if you click on svg path element, above code will get you to the desired span element. 
[demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gpj5ra?file=demo.js).

Also, we can prevent clicks on parent div using `pointer-events:none` CSS rule. But this will create huge unclickable area. And the SVG icon is also clickable :/ We'll have to make a lot of changes in CSS to bring the desired span in front of/covering everything.

---

**Old answer**
If you are trying to figure out which item got clicked then you can define onclick handler like this:

```html
<ListItem button key={text}
   onClick={(e) => console.log(text) } >
OR
<ListItem button key={text}
   onClick={(e) => handleSelect(text) } >
```

This will give you the list item name right away. Then you can open corresponding content.

Comment: I've clearly already implemented `onClick`. The question has nothing to do with how to figure out which item got clicked, but how to prevent the parent `div` from being clicked instead of the child `ListItem`.

Comment: I see. I've updated the answer check now.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a CSS problem. You need to make the child elements width and height equal to the parent elements width and height. This is true for every element which is inline by default and you want to work with it.

Here are some docs about the CSS box model:

- [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model)
- [understanding the inline box model](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/)

---

In this case, you want to change the display element in `ListItem` to `div`

**AKA**

```
<ListItem component="div">
    // some stuff
</ListItem>
```

Comment: I tried adding `component = 'div'` into the `<ListItem>`s, leaving everything else unchanged, but it had no effect